# Type error Cannot find properties of undefined (reading id)

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm at a lost here.  I have a couple of services, one has been working for month and the newer one for some weeks, then all of a sudden a couple of days ago I start to get two console errors "Cannot read properties of undefined(reading id). I have not changed anything.

If I can fix one then I can understand the other because they both have the same error.  When I did my research it talks about initializing.

This is an e-commerce site, when the user clicks on the heart it gets added to wishlistitems in my json file.  The user should have the ability to go to favorites and it shows all of the wishlist items. As I stated it was working now I get errors. I have a two models(class) I have two components wishlist-list and wishlistitems the html will display the url for the images and  I have a serive.

Here is the wish Model

```
  import { Product } from './product';


  export class Wish {
   id:number;
   productId: number;
   productName: string;
   description: string;
   qty:number;
   price: number;
   imageUrl: string;

  constructor(id:number, product:Product, qty=1, ){

  this.id = id;
  this.productId = product.id; 
  this.price = product.price;
  this.productName = product.name;
  this.qty = qty;
  this.imageUrl = product.imageUrl;
  this.description = product.description;
 }
}
```

Here is the Product Model

```
   export class Product {
   id:number;
   name: string;
   description: string;
   price: number;
   imageUrl: string;
   constructor(id:number, name, description="", price=0, imageUrl="" ){

  this.id=id
  this.name = name 
  this.description = description
  this.price= price
  this.imageUrl = imageUrl
  }

}
```

Here is my Wishlist component

```
 import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
 import {ProductService} from 'src/app/services/product.service'
 import { MessengerService } from 'src/app/services/messenger.service';
 import { WishlistService } from 'src/app/services/wishlist.service';
 import { WishlistItemService } from '@app/services/wishlist-item.service';
 import { Wish} from 'src/app/models/wish';
 import {Product} from 'src/app/models/product';


 @Component({
  selector: 'app-wishlist-list',
  templateUrl: './wishlist-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./wishlist-list.component.scss']
})

    export class WishlistListComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() product: any;

    productList: Product[]= [];
    wishitemList: Wish[]= [];
    wishItems =  [];

    constructor( private msg: MessengerService, private productService: ProductService,
    private wishlistService: WishlistService,
    private _wishlistitemService: WishlistItemService  ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
     this.loadwishlistList()
  }



   loadwishlistList(){
     alert("Loading wish list item");
     this._wishlistitemService.getWishlistitem().subscribe((items: Wish[]) => {
     console.log("A wish List  Item" + items);
     this.wishItems=items;

   })

  }

}
```

Here is my service

```
   @Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
 })

 export class WishlistItemService {

    product:any;
    id:number;

    wishlistitemUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/wishlistitem';   //I have this in a api file

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }



     getWishlistitem(): Observable<Wish[]>{
     return this.http.get<Wish[]>(wishlistitemUrl).pipe(
     map((result: any[]) => {
     let wishItems: Wish[] =[];

     for(let item of result) {

     let productExists = false

     for(let i in wishItems){
      if(wishItems[i].productId === item.product.id){   //this is line I get error on
       wishItems[i].qty++
       productExists = true
       break;
    } 
  }

    
    if (!productExists){

      wishItems.push(new Wish(item.id,item.product, item.name));
    }
   }

       return wishItems;
  })
  );

 }

}
```

I am at a lost here for it to work then stop working.  I'm pulling my hair out, I tried making adjustments but nothing work. I read something about initializing, I'm in need of help.

Thanking You Advance
PH

Comment: Can you provide the JSON response data received from API to the question? Thanks.

Comment: At least one `item` in the `result` you get back from the server does not have a `product` property. So `item.product` will be undefined, which leads to an error when trying to access `item.product.id`

Comment: I'm not getting any response from the api before it was loading the images

Comment: Hello derpirscher:

Comment: Hello derpirscher: You were correct , I reviewed my json file carefully it appears that while testing out some new code I added some id;s only were added to the wishlistitem  object in the file.   Thank you this answered the question for the second error I was getting  on my other component in which the code is very similar.